MQTT connection NODE-RED ; variable for username and password
i would need some help for my node-red code,
i am curently using the "mqtt-out" to connect to a mqtt broker
for the moment, i have put my variable in the server and port : ${BROKER_MQTT_HOST} and ${BROKER_MQTT_PORT}
but , i can't pass them for the username and password , if you have any idea it would be great
here is my node :
[
{
"id": "fbd24183c1d90d26",
"type": "mqtt out",
"z": "6612f3330cf9f37d",
"name": "Broker MQTT",
"topic": "${BROKER_MQTT_TOPIC}",
"qos": "",
"retain": "",
"respTopic": "",
"contentType": "",
"userProps": "",
"correl": "",
"expiry": "",
"broker": "6706370c3a497665",
"x": 820,
"y": 580,
"wires": []
},
{
"id": "6706370c3a497665",
"type": "mqtt-broker",
"name": "",
"broker": "${BROKER_MQTT_HOST}",
"port": "${BROKER_MQTT_PORT}",
"clientid": "",
"autoConnect": true,
"usetls": false,
"protocolVersion": "4",
"keepalive": "60",
"cleansession": true,
"birthTopic": "",
"birthQos": "0",
"birthPayload": "",
"birthMsg": {},
"closeTopic": "",
"closeQos": "0",
"closePayload": "",
"closeMsg": {},
"willTopic": "",
"willQos": "0",
"willPayload": "",
"willMsg": {},
"userProps": "",
"sessionExpiry": "",
"credentials": {
"user": "",
"password": ""
}
}
]

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can use environment variables in any field including the username and password in the config node. But credentials will not be present in the flow file as they are stored separately. It's not clear from the question what the actual problem is

ok i had just to fill the user and password with variable , it work just like the other field
